# Json.Net deserializing fails with collection of derived types

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, serialization, json.net

After trying almost any solution here on SO ([this one is the lastest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880574/json-net-how-to-deserialize-collection-of-interface-instances)) I gave up and decided to ask for your help.

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize a collection of objects that extend a common abstract class.
Serialization goes fine, but it fails when deserializing, throwing this exception:

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
>
> Could not create an instance of type Plugins.BaseModel. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Widgets[0].BackgroundColor', line 1, position 60.

Before goind into the code, here's the string that I'm trying to deserialize (I've indented the string to make it more readable!):

```
{
  "Widgets": [
    {
      "$type": "SimpleBatteryModel",
      "BackgroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 229,
        "G": 20,
        "B": 0
      },
      "ForegroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 255,
        "G": 255,
        "B": 255
      },
      "BackgroundOpacity": 1.0,
      "WidgetPosition": {
        "Left": 157.0,
        "Top": 302.0,
        "Right": 0.0,
        "Bottom": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "DummyModel",
      "Text": "Dummy Widget (4)",
      "BackgroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 229,
        "G": 20,
        "B": 0
      },
      "ForegroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 255,
        "G": 255,
        "B": 255
      },
      "BackgroundOpacity": 1.0,
      "WidgetPosition": {
        "Left": 0.0,
        "Top": 0.0,
        "Right": 0.0,
        "Bottom": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "SimpleBatteryModel",
      "BackgroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 229,
        "G": 20,
        "B": 0
      },
      "ForegroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 255,
        "G": 255,
        "B": 255
      },
      "BackgroundOpacity": 1.0,
      "WidgetPosition": {
        "Left": 330.0,
        "Top": 0.0,
        "Right": 0.0,
        "Bottom": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "DummyModel",
      "Text": "Dummy Widget (4)",
      "BackgroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 229,
        "G": 20,
        "B": 0
      },
      "ForegroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 255,
        "G": 255,
        "B": 255
      },
      "BackgroundOpacity": 1.0,
      "WidgetPosition": {
        "Left": 180.0,
        "Top": 700.0,
        "Right": 0.0,
        "Bottom": 0.0
      }
    },
    {
      "$type": "SimpleBatteryModel",
      "BackgroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 229,
        "G": 20,
        "B": 0
      },
      "ForegroundColor": {
        "A": 255,
        "R": 255,
        "G": 255,
        "B": 255
      },
      "BackgroundOpacity": 1.0,
      "WidgetPosition": {
        "Left": 0.0,
        "Top": 650.0,
        "Right": 0.0,
        "Bottom": 0.0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

(*`Widgets` is an `ObservableCollection<BaseModel>`*)

While I'm not posting my `JsonSerializerSettings` because I've got this error with any combination of settings, here's a little snippet of my code (focusing just on the serialized properties).

(class `namespace Plugins.BaseModel`)

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public abstract class BaseModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...other stuff...        
    [JsonProperty]
    public Color BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return _backgroundColor; }
        set
        {
            if (_backgroundColor == value) return;
            _backgroundColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => BackgroundColor);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public Color ForegroundColor
    {
        get { return _foregroundColor; }
        set
        {
            if (_foregroundColor == value) return;
            _foregroundColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ForegroundColor);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public double BackgroundOpacity
    {
        get { return _backgroundOpacity; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _backgroundOpacity) return;
            _backgroundOpacity = value;
            _backgroundColor.A = (byte) (_backgroundOpacity*255);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => BackgroundOpacity);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => BackgroundColor);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public Thickness WidgetPosition
    {
        get { return _widgetPosition; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _widgetPosition) return;
            _widgetPosition = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => WidgetPosition);
        }
    }
    ...other stuff...
}
```

(class `Plugins.widgets.PRIVATE.Dummy.DummyModel`)

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class DummyModel : BaseModel
{
 ... other stuff...
 [JsonProperty]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (_text == value) return;
            _text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
        }
    }
... other stuff ...
}
```

(class `Plugins.widgets.Battery.SimpleBattery.SimpleBatteryModel`)

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class SimpleBatteryModel : BaseModel
{
    ... other stuff ...
}
```

As you can see, both the concrete classes are inheriting properties from the base class, and those properties are serialized without errors.
The problem comes when I try to deserialize, as the deserializer tries to create an instance of the base class instead of the derived one.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

EDIT:
Since you're sking, here are my current settings (based on the answer linked at the start of the question)

```
_settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto, Binder = new TypeNameSerializationBinder("Plugins.{0}, Plugins")};
```

EDIT 2:
Here's my project's structure:

```
Main Solution
             \- Main App (WP app project)
                        \- MainPage.xaml
             \- Model    (WP C# library project)
                        \- MainViewModel.cs (contains the collection Widgets that I'm serializing)
             \- Plugins  (WP C# library project)
                        \- BaseModel.cs (the main abstract class)
                        \- widgets.PRIVATE.Dummy.DummyModel.cs (one of the concrete classes)
                        \- widgets.Battery.SimpleBattery.SimpleBatteryModel.cs (the other concrete class)
```

where `Main App` references `Model` which references `Plugins`

Comment: What does your `TypeNameSerializationBinder` look like?

Comment: I don't have the project with me now, but I copied the one in this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15881570/1094430

Comment: OK, thanks.  Next question-- are your plugins in different assemblies?

Comment: I've added a rough view of my project's structure, check the updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  One last question.  Have you tried not using the custom binder, but instead setting `TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` (both when serializing and deserializing)?

Comment: I've tried it now, serialized output is changed but I got the _same_ exception on deserializing.

Comment: OK, do both of your plugin classes have a default constructor (i.e. a constructor that takes no parameters)?

Comment: Everything has a default constructor, even the abstract `BaseModel` class. (shouldn't we move this to chat?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42664/discussion-between-brian-rogers-and-steptnt)

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar problem, how did you get it working finally ?

Comment: Hi there, I'm sorry but after 2 years it's quite difficult to remember what I did. Probably I just gave up on tha project :( I suggest you to start a new question.

Comment: @StepTNT I'm so sad to hear that =/  yes I did start a new question but nobody seems to know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958062/deserialization-nightmare-could-not-create-an-instance-of-type-t-type-is-an   I spent 4 days on that, read every question, read all google, read the source code, and so on. I've never been that puzzled by a bug as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you serialize and deserialize but make sure you are using the same `JsonSerializerSettings` to deserialize as well. It doesn't have to be the same instance but it must have the same options in order to work on deserialization.

Comment: I'm even using the same instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Well, it was a wild guess as this issue may come from different settings of serialization/deserialization and I haven't seen the code. Have you tried to set TypeNameHandling.Objects in JsonSerializerSettings ?

Comment: Already tried it. Serialized output changes, but the exception is always the same :\ I've edited my question with my current settings.