# Does Json.NET support Serialization/Desrialization to IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, json.net

[This](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) Json.NET page does not explicitly mention support of IEnumerable. But of testing, it seems to work. Can I rely on this?

Comment: Yes.  [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherits from `IEnumerable`: `public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable`.  And from the Json.NET docs: [Serialization Guide: IEnumerable, Lists, and Arrays](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Lists): **.NET lists (types that inherit from IEnumerable) and .NET arrays are converted to JSON arrays.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialization is not a problem because it uses the type of the serialized object

a generic ienumerable ( IEnumerable<> ) can be deserialized because its inner type is enough for the deserializator to understand what to read, but a generic ienumerable is just an interface that need some help to be deserialized, like an explicit JsonConverter

of course i refer to serialize/deserialize to typed object and not JObject

this is a question similar to your: [JSON.NET - how to deserialize collection of interface-instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880574/json-net-how-to-deserialize-collection-of-interface-instances)

and this blog article explain further: http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/08/30/deserializing-interface-properties-using-json-net/

Comment: Json.NET somehow manages to do this even without mentioning an explicit JsonConverter. Why?

Comment: are you referring to generic or non generic ienumerable?
anyway step into debugger and inspect the elements generated into your ienumerable to see what's their types