# Designing Classes With Interface In C# (JSON.NET)

Tags: c#, json, interface, class-design, json.net

I am in the process of designing an itemization system for a game.  I am creating a bunch of interfaces (IItem, IConsumable, IEquipable, IWeapon, etc...) to define what type of functionality is possible with items and then a number of classes (Weapon, Potion, etc...) the define the actual item types.

Now when saving out the player, the data is going to be stored as a JSON file (using the JSON.NET library) and will included the players inventory which will include these items.  The issue is that when I try to deserialize the JSON file to an object when reading in the file, how will I be able to tell the JSON.NET library what type of class this is?

One thing I thought of and have not had time to try yet is that all my objects that get serialized into JSON have a DTO version of the object that is used in conjunction with the JSON.NET library.  What I though about trying is maybe I could add in a property to the DTO called ClassType and then when reading the file into the application, I would first read the object in as an anonymous type.  Then based on the ClassType property, I would convert it to the proper type.  The 2 issues I have with this is that 1. it seems like a very ugly solution and 2. I am not even sure if that is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Json.NET converters to deserialize properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties)

Answer (score 1):

(Copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties))

In cases here I have not had control over the incoming JSON (and so cannot ensure that it includes a $type property) I have written a custom converter that just allows you to explicitly specify the concrete type:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Something>))]
    public ISomething TheThing { get; set; }
}
```

This just uses the default serializer implementation from Json.Net whilst explicitly specifying the concrete type.

The source code and an overview are available on [this blog post](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/08/30/deserializing-interface-properties-using-json-net/).

Answer (score 0):

You should know the concrete type when you are serializing. So you can use `TypeNameHandling` of JSON.NET.

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/08/13/json-net-3-5-release-8-3-5-final.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+jamesnewtonking+%28James+Newton-King%29

Comment: I'll give it a try (hopefully that feature works with the 2.0 version of the library as I have to use that version).

Comment: Just checked. Nope, version 2.0 does not support TypeNameHandling.

Comment: Well that sucks, will have to find another way around it I guess.