# Deserializing IList objects with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, json.net

I'm using a ConcreteCollectionTypeConverter to deserialize objects of type IList. I'm probably doing it very wrong because I keep getting the exception "Cannot convert List to IList"

My object inteface looks something like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public IMyInterface {

    [JsonProperty("associatedContact")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteCollectionTypeConverter<IList<ISomeOtherInterface>, List<SomeOtherInterface>>))]
    IList<ISomeOtherInterface> MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

My object implementation looks like this:

```
public MyImplementation : IMyInterface {

    public List<SomeOtherImplementation> MyObject { get; set; }

    public MyImplementations () {
        MyObject = new List<SomeOtherImplementation>();          
    }
}
```

My Json Converter looks like this:

```
class ConcreteCollectionTypeConverter<TInterface, TImplementation> : JsonConverter where TImplementation : TInterface
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<TImplementation>(reader);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the deserialization method somewhere else in my project like this:

```
var myDeserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyImplementation>(jsonObject.ToString());
```

My jsonObject mentioned above is correctly parsed.

I know this is possible because I've seen a comment here on SO from a user caliming he's done it ([Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net) - first comment of the accepted answer).

This approach works fine for non-collection items (i.e. deserializing an object of an interface type IIterface MyObject with JsonConverer(typeof(ConcreteTypeCOnverter)) works).

If I use only Lists instead of ILists, I don't even need the Type Converter, but my requirements are to assure usage of ICollections because of possible non standard implementations.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will work for what you need:

```
public class ConcreteListTypeConverter<TInterface, TImplementation> : JsonConverter where TImplementation : TInterface 
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var res = serializer.Deserialize<List<TImplementation>>(reader);
        return res.ConvertAll(x => (TInterface) x);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```