# Why does this ploymorphic List property go null when adding additional objects to the list?

Tags: c#-4.0, polymorphism

Consider the following:

```
public class VideoContainer<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public List<VideoContainer<T>> VideoContainers { get; set; }
}

public class Perspective : VideoContainer<Perspective>
{
    public List<VideoContainer<SourceContainer>> VideoContainers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to ensure `VideoContainer<Perspective>.VideoContainers` can only contain `VideoContainer<SourceContainer>` types.

I add a new `Perspective` object to a `List<Perspective>` with three `VideoContainers`.  The problem is that when I add a new Perspective to the list, the previously-added `Perspective.VideoContainers` is null.

Why is this happening?

Comment: your object model is wrong. `new` is "shadowing" the base class member.

Comment: @HighCore - I removed the `new` statement, and also removed `VideoContainers` from the base class.  Edited above code to reflect this. Same issue.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need two generic types:

```
public class VideoContainer<T, U>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<VideoContainer<U>> VideoContainers { get; set; }
}

public class Perspective : VideoContainer<Perspective, SourceContainer>
{
    // No longer declare the list, just use it... it's now:
    // public List<VideoContainer<SourceContainer>> VideoContainers { get; set; }
}
```