# JsonConverter Attribute : deserialize using custom constructor and Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, json.net, autofac

Am using a custom JsonConverter to convert my JSON object. This is achieved via the JsonConverter attribute to the IQuery object below

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter<IQuery>))]
public interface IQuery
{
}
```

The custom generic class is below (some bits removed for brevity)

```
public class CustomConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    // This should be created via AutoFac
    public ICustomObjectCreator<T> ObjectCreator { get; set; }

    // This default constructr always gets called
    public CustomConverter() {}

    // I want to call this constructor
    [JsonConstructor]
    public CustomConverter(ICustomObjectCreator<T> objectCreator)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        // Load JObject from stream 
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Create target object based on JObject 
        var target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        // Populate the object properties 
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    protected T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        var type = jObject.GetValue("type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>();
        return ObjectCreator.Create(type);
    }
}
```

The ICustomObjectConverter interface is simple

```
public interface ICustomObjectCreator<out T>
{
    T Create(string type);
}
```

and one of its implementation

```
public class QueryObjectCreator : ICustomObjectCreator<IQuery>
{
    public IQuery Create(string type)
    {
        // ... some logic to create a concrete object
        return (IQuery)concreteObject;
    }
}
```

Finally, Autofac is wired to honor the above

```
builder.RegisterType<QueryObjectCreator>()
       .As<ICustomObjectCreator<IQuery>>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Problems:

1. When CustomJsonConverter is called, only its default constructor is called. The JsonConstructor is NEVER called.
2. If I remove the default constructor, then the whole JsonConverter is NEVER called!

I have an inklinkg that AutoFac is never being called when JsonConverter is being invoked. I even tried property injection to construct QueryObjectConstruct explicitly, but even that is never called. How can I make it work so that my QueryObjectCretor is injected via DI?

I found [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithDependencyInjection.htm) article about Dependency Injection and JSON.net deserialization. However, that is for manual resolve using DeserializeObject<>() call, how can I, if it works, make it work with JsonConverter attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Just for reference, can be helpful to see this answer to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40974579/3768871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following steps to achieve your goal:

1. Create a non generic interface for your `ICustomObjectCreator` interface, to make creating objects more convenient.
2. Introduce a generic `ObjectCreatorBase<T>` base class which calls your generic `Create` method.
3. Create and set default settings which are used by `JsonConvert`.
4. Set the `AutofacContractResolver` as `ContractResolver`.

See the following example to get you started:

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<QueryObjectCreator>()
        .As<ICustomObjectCreator<IQuery>>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    var container = builder.Build();

    Func<JsonSerializerSettings> settingsFactory = () =>
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new AutofacContractResolver(container);

        return settings;
    };

    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = settingsFactory;

    var myObject = new MyObject { Query = new Query(42) };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

    myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(myObject.Query.MyProperty);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class AutofacContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacContractResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        var customObjectCreatorType = typeof(ICustomObjectCreator<>).MakeGenericType(objectType);

        if (!_container.IsRegistered(customObjectCreatorType))
            return contract;

        var customObjectCreator = (ICustomObjectCreator) _container.Resolve(customObjectCreatorType);

        // I don't know how you want to obtain the string which shall be passed to CreateObject
        contract.DefaultCreator = () => customObjectCreator.CreateObject("XYZ");
        return contract;
    }
}

public interface ICustomObjectCreator
{
    object CreateObject(string type);
}

public interface ICustomObjectCreator<out T> : ICustomObjectCreator
{
    T Create(string type);
}

public abstract class ObjectCreatorBase<T> : ICustomObjectCreator<T>
{
    public object CreateObject(string type)
    {
        return Create(type);
    }

    public abstract T Create(string type);
}

public class QueryObjectCreator : ObjectCreatorBase<IQuery>
{
    public override IQuery Create(string type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create called");

        // ... some logic to create a concrete object
        var concreteObject = new Query();
        return (IQuery)concreteObject;
    }
}

public interface IQuery
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Query : IQuery
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Query()
    {
    }

    public Query(int myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public IQuery Query { get; set; }
}
```

The output should be

```
Create called
42
```

Maybe you could simplify the code by removing all `ICustomObjectCreator` instances by simply using Autofac to create your objects directly.

### Update

The first approach works, but it does not take into account that you need to get a string to decide which kind of object you are creating (`type`).

To get this to work you could the following:

1. Register the `CustomConverter` as generic.
2. Overwrite the `ResolveContractConverter` method to return an instance of the converter in case any `ICustomObjectCreator` has been registered for the type.
3. Alter the `DefaultSettings` so that the `AutofacContractResolver` will be used.

See the following example:

```
void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<QueryObjectCreator>()
        .As<ICustomObjectCreator<IQuery>>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CustomConverter<>)).AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    var container = builder.Build();

    Func<JsonSerializerSettings> settingsFactory = () =>
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new AutofacContractResolver(container);

        return settings;
    };

    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = settingsFactory;

    var myObject = new MyObject { Query = new Query(42) };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

    myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(myObject.Query.MyProperty);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class AutofacContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacContractResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        var customObjectCreatorType = typeof(ICustomObjectCreator<>).MakeGenericType(objectType);
        if (!_container.IsRegistered(customObjectCreatorType))
            return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);

        var customConverterType = typeof(CustomConverter<>).MakeGenericType(objectType);
        return (JsonConverter) _container.Resolve(customConverterType);
    }
}

public class CustomConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    // This should be created via AutoFac
    public ICustomObjectCreator<T> ObjectCreator { get; }

    // This default constructr always gets called
    public CustomConverter() { }

    // I want to call this constructor
    public CustomConverter(ICustomObjectCreator<T> objectCreator)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor called");
        ObjectCreator = objectCreator;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        // Load JObject from stream 
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Create target object based on JObject 
        var target = Create(objectType, jObject);

        // Populate the object properties 
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    protected T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        var type = jObject.GetValue("type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>();
        return ObjectCreator.Create(type);
    }
}

public interface ICustomObjectCreator<out T> 
{
    T Create(string type);
}

public class QueryObjectCreator : ICustomObjectCreator<IQuery>
{
    public IQuery Create(string type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Create called");

        // ... some logic to create a concrete object
        var concreteObject = new Query();
        return (IQuery)concreteObject;
    }
}

public interface IQuery
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Query : IQuery
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Query()
    {
    }

    public Query(int myProperty)
    {
        MyProperty = myProperty;
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public IQuery Query { get; set; }
}
```

The output should be

```
Constructor called
Create called
42
```

Here is the [.NET Fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HsddzL) for the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose an autofac setting like the following:

```
public class AutofacContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacContractResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonObjectContract contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        // use Autofac to create types that have been registered with it
        if (_container.IsRegistered(objectType))
        {
           contract.DefaultCreator = () => _container.Resolve(objectType);
        }  

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then, suppose your class is like this:

```
public class TaskController
{
    private readonly ITaskRepository _repository;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public TaskController(ITaskRepository repository, ILogger logger)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public ITaskRepository Repository
    {
        get { return _repository; }
    }

    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return _logger; }
    }
}
```

Therefore, the usage of the resolver in deserialization could be like:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<TaskRepository>().As<ITaskRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<TaskController>();
builder.Register(c => new LogService(new DateTime(2000, 12, 12))).As<ILogger>();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

AutofacContractResolver contractResolver = new AutofacContractResolver(container);

string json = @"{
      'Logger': {
        'Level':'Debug'
      }
}";

// ITaskRespository and ILogger constructor parameters are injected by Autofac 
TaskController controller = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskController>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = contractResolver
});

Console.WriteLine(controller.Repository.GetType().Name);
```

You can see more details in http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithDependencyInjection.htm