# Where is the flaw in my attempt to implement a JsonConverter that handles interfaces and abstract classes?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to create an implementation of `JsonConverter` that can deserialize `interface`s and `abstract` classes by using the **first** derived type that can be deserialized through default deserialization. Here is my unit test to give you can idea:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void BaseTypeConverterCanConvertPolymorphicClass()
    {
        var polymorphicClass = new ConcreteFoo()
        {
            SomeString = "test string",
            Bar = new ConcreteBar()
            {
                SomeInt = 18237
            }
        };

        string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(polymorphicClass);

        IFoo deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFoo>(serialized);

        Assert.IsTrue(deserialized is ConcreteFoo);
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BaseTypeConverter))]
    private interface IFoo
    {
        [JsonProperty("someString")]
        string SomeString { get; }

        [JsonProperty("bar")]
        IBar Bar { get; }
    }

    private class ConcreteFoo : IFoo
    {
        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        public IBar Bar { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BaseTypeConverter))]
    private interface IBar
    {
        [JsonProperty("someInt")]
        int SomeInt { get; }
    }

    private class ConcreteBar : IBar
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    }

    private class OtherConcreteBar : IBar
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("someDouble")]
        public double SomeDouble { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my implementation:

```
public class BaseTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static IDictionary<Type, ICollection<Type>> cache = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection<Type>>();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAbstract || objectType.IsInterface;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable<Type> derived = GetDerivedTypes(objectType);

        var defaultSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

        foreach (Type type in derived)
        {
            object deserialized = defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, type);

            if (deserialized != null)
            {
                return deserialized;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException($"Could not deserialize type {objectType} into any of the dervied types: {string.Join(",", derived)}.");
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"Should never have to write because {nameof(CanWrite)} is {CanWrite}.");
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetDerivedTypes(Type baseType)
    {
        if (cache.ContainsKey(baseType))
        {
            return cache[baseType];
        }

        var derivedTypes =
            (from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
             from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
             where baseType.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType)
                && baseType != assemblyType
             select assemblyType).ToList();

        cache[baseType] = derivedTypes;

        return derivedTypes;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm finding is that somehow `defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, type);` is re-calling my `ReadJson` method rather than the "default" one like I expect. In other words, it calls it on type `ConcreteFoo`.

Where is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: I have the impression that this line won't work: `IFoo deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFoo>(serialized);` - given that you might have **N** implementations of `IFoo`, how is the serializer supposed to know which type to deserialize? You should specify the type of the object to deserialize, something like `IFoo deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConcreteFoo>(serialized);`

Comment: Also, do you really need to create a custom `JsonConverter`?

Comment: @RuiJarimba The idea is that it tries "normal" deserialization on each of the N implementations and returns the first that works. Maybe later I'll have it throw an exception if more than one works. But this is a custom converter that is needed if I can't use type-name handling for some reason (doesn't matter the reason).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net)

Comment: I believe the solution to your problem is in the link I posted, there are a few different approaches you can try