# Deserializing List<Interface> using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a json back to the object.
I have a List of interface in the object, which on deserializing is failing.
*Pasting the code below.*

### Model

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public List<IAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public abstract class IAddress
{
    public string HomeTown { get; set; }
}

public class Address : IAddress
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

*The code to serialize and deserialize are as follows:*

```cs
var personObj = new Person
{
    Name = "John Doe",
    Age = 30,
    Addresses = new List<IAddress>
    {
        new Address
        {
            Location = "location1",
            Street = "Vzk",
            Zip = "686670"
        }
    }
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personObj);
System.Console.WriteLine(json);

/*
{
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Age": 30,
    "Addresses": [{
        "Location": "location1",
        "Street": "Vzk",
        "Zip": "686670",
        "HomeTown": null
    }]
}
*/

var p2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });

System.Console.WriteLine((p2.Addresses[0] as Address).Zip);
```

*The error that I'm getting is:*

> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type Human.IAddress. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Addresses[0].Location', line 1, position 53.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
>      at Parser.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\expmts\csharp\Person\Parser\Program.cs:line 82

Is there any way to make `NewtonSoft` understand that, for type `IAddress`, `Address` is the type to be initiated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe a douplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net?

Comment: just change interface to class. Error contains all needed information

Comment: Either all list items are of type `Employee` so you make it a `List<Employee>`, or the list items can be of different types and then you need something in the serialised form to indicate the type of each item, i.e. the *discriminator* feature in the OpenAPI spec.

Comment: This is a special use case, where I'm forced to do it this way due to compatibility issues. I have an option `[XmlInclude(typeof(Address)]` in case of `xml serialization`. What I'm looking for is something similar to it but in `json`.