# Serialization issues while using inheritance with the System.Text.Json lib

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am replacing the Newtonsoft library by the System.Text.Json and the result is quite different. I am using inheritance and have made an example for simplicity.

```
public interface ID
{
    int DProp { get; set; }
}

public class D : ID
{
    public int DProp { get; set; }
}

public interface IC
{
    IEnumerable<IY> CList { get; set; }
}

public class C : D, IC
{
    public IEnumerable<IY> CList { get; set; }
}

public interface IB : IC
{    
    IEnumerable<IZ> BList { get; set; }
}
 
public class B : C, IB
{
    public IEnumerable<IZ> BList { get; set; }
}

public interface IA
{
    IEnumerable<IB> BList { get; set; }
 
    string SomeProp { get; set; }
}

public class A : IA
{ 
    public IEnumerable<IB> BList { get; set; }

    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}

//Creating objects
var yList = new List<IY>()
{
    new Y() { YProp = 2 },
};
var zList = new List<IZ>()
{
    new Z() { ZProp = 2 },
};
var bList = new List<IB>
{
    new B { CList = yList, BList = zList, DProp = 1 },
};
IA a = new A();
a.BList = bList;
a.SomeProp = "123";

var jsonSerialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a);
```

And the jsonSerialized result is:

```
{
    "BList": [
        {
            "BList": [
                {
                    "ZProp": 2
                }
            ],
            "CList": [
                {
                    "YProp": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "SomeProp": "123"
}
```

The question is, why is the DProp not present in the output?
B derives from C and C from D.

Comment: You haven't defined `IY` or `IZ`, or `Y`, or `Z`.

Comment: Your problem boils down to the fact that the serializer only looks at properties defined by the interface rather than the most-derived type. This is a common pitfall and already has an answer here: [Serialize objects implementing interface with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373915/serialize-objects-implementing-interface-with-system-text-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the "inheritance" of interfaces.

blist is defined as `IEnumerable<IB>`.

So you have the following interface "inheritance":  IB implements IC.

To include ID.Prop you need IC to implement ID.

Comment: This is implemented in a big project and I kind of know that there is a missing inheritance but the thing is Newtonsoft works with the way it is currently implemented, so the question is why, is there a bug in the Newtonsoft library?

Comment: @Bonomi - no, it is a design difference between Newtonsoft and System.Text.Json.  Newtonsoft serializes all the properties of the actual object being serialized.  System.Text.Json only serializes the declared properties of the reference to the object by default. See [How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

```
var bList = new List<IB>
{
    new B { CList = yList, BList = zList, DProp = 1 },
};
```

You've created a "list of IB" while instantiating "B". Without re-casting you've lost access to what B inherits; i.e. DProp.