# Deserialization of inteface types not supported using System.Text.JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, system.text.json

I am passing in a valid JSON object to my controller on my .net core 3 web api application.  Doing so, I get the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'OrderTranslationContracts.OrderContracts+IImportOrderLineModel'

So I looked in my code and I have the following concrete implementation of an Interface.  Here is the line I think that's throwing the error:

```
   public List<OrderContracts.IImportOrderLineModel> Lines { get; set; }
```

Here is the portion of the JSON I am passing into the controller:

```
"lines": [
        {
            "orderNumber": "LV21131327",
            "lineNumber": 1,
            "itemId": "3083US",
            "customerItemId": "3083US",
            "quantity": 3,
            "price": 0.00,
            "quantityBackOrdered": null,
            "comments": "",
            "pickLocation": "",
            "orderFilled": "O",
            "hostUom": null,
            "type": null
        }
```

So I know the JSON is valid.  Here is the signature for the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<List<ImportOrderModel>> Post([FromBody] List<ImportOrderModel> orders)
    {
        var response = await _validateOrder.ValidateAllOrdersAsync(orders, null);
        return response;
    }
```

I don't even break into this code as I am assuming that the JSON deserializer is throwing the error as it tries to convert it.  So how do I over come this error?  I am bound by the concrete implementation for the interface so I can't change the interface I need to work with what I have here if possible.  If that isn't possible, are there any "work arounds" for this?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Here:

```
public List<OrderContracts.IImportOrderLineModel> Lines { get; set; }
```

Your list is of type `IImportOrderLineModel` Interface.

it should be like

```
 public List<ImportOrderLineModel> Lines { get; set; }
```

that `ImportOrderLineModel` is a class that implements it like:

```
public class ImportOrderLineModel : IImportOrderLineModel
{
    //......
}
```

Comment: OP should use a JsonConverter to map interface to concrete types. It defeats the purpose of interfaces (and violates SOLID), to use the concrete implementations in this way.

Comment: Thanks I put this in and it was able to get past the error.

Comment: This is just a workaround and doesn't solve the problem. Please use @user12447201 his solutions

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problems with `HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync`
I tried `httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ICustomer>(url);`

And I got the error:

> Deserialization of inteface types not supported using System.Text.JSON

From what I was able to find out, a model has to be available to deserialize an InterfaceType.
My solution defines the model in the interface using data annotations.

1. Create a TypeConverter (I found this class here: [Casting interfaces for deserialization in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net))

   **using Newtonsoft.Json;**

   ```
   public class ConcreteTypeConverter<TConcrete> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            //assume we can convert to anything for now
            return true;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            //explicitly specify the concrete type we want to create
            return serializer.Deserialize<TConcrete>(reader);
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            //use the default serialization - it works fine
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }
   ```

2 Add Data Annotations in your Interface (`[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<AddressModel>))]`)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public interface ICustomer
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<AddressModel>))]
    IAddress Address { get; set; }
}
```

3 Unfortunatly `HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync` does not use Newtonsoft. I wrote my own method

```
public async static Task<T> GetJsonAsync<T>(HttpClient client, string url)
{
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.ReadToEnd(), new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            NullValueHandling= NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
    }
}
```

4 Now i can use:

```
 HttpClient httpClient= new HttpClient();
 string url="https://example.com/api/customerlist";
 var myCustomerList[]=await GetJsonAsync<CutomerModel[]>(httpClient, url);
```

Comment: How does this work without annotations? What if I have an interface `IFoo` that has property `IEnumerable<IBar>` ?

Comment: I did not find  solution without annotation for a Interface as property, because you need to have a model for the api-contract. The solution without annotation is, that you use IEnumerable<Bar> instead of IEnumerable<IBar> where Bar implements IBar.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post after getting an exception also, but found the use of attributes a little counterproductive.
The whole reason of using interfaces is that these know nothing about the implementation. By specifying the attribute, the interface becomes strongly coupled to the implementation which defeats its purpose of using it.

Thats why i came up with another solution which works for me without strongly reference it with an attribute.

#### Model

```
public class Budget : ModelBase, IBudget
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the BudgetId property value.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Identity]
    public Guid BudgetId
    {
        get => GetValue<Guid>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Description property value.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Description
    {
        get => GetValue<string>();
        set => SetValue(value);
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Interface

```
public interface IBudget : IModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the BudgetId property value.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [Identity]
    Guid BudgetId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Description property value.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    string Description { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

#### TypeResolver

```
public static class TypeResolvers
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> GetBudgetsTypeResolvers()
    {
        return typeInfo =>
        {
            if (typeInfo.Type == typeof(IBudget))
                typeInfo.CreateObject = () => new Budget();
        };
    }
}
```

#### Dependency injection (inside hostbuilder for example)

```
services.AddSingleton<JsonSerializerOptions>((s) =>
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
        ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip,
        AllowTrailingCommas = true,
        NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString | JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString,
        ReferenceHandler = null,
        TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
        {
            Modifiers = { TypeResolvers.GetBudgetsTypeResolvers() }
        }
    };

    options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    options.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeJsonConverter());
    options.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeOffsetJsonConverter());

    return options;
});
services.TryAddSingleton<IRestService, RestService>();
```

#### RestService

```
public partial class RestService : BaseRestService, IRestService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="authenticationService"></param>
    /// <param name="languageService"></param>
    /// <param name="exceptionHandlerService"></param>
    /// <param name="configurationOptions"></param>
    public RestService(
        IContext context,
        IAuthenticationService authenticationService,
        ILanguageService languageService,
        IExceptionHandlerService exceptionHandlerService,
        JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions,
        IOptions<ConfigurationOptions> configurationOptions)
        : base(context, authenticationService, languageService, exceptionHandlerService, jsonSerializerOptions, configurationOptions)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the budget by identifier asynchronous.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
    /// <returns>Task&lt;Budget&gt;.</returns>
    public Task<IBudget> GetBudgetByIdAsync(Guid id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
        GetAsync<IBudget>($"{_configurationOptions.ServiceEndpoint}/{ControllerNames.Budgets}/{id}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the budget asynchronous.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The e.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
    /// <returns>Task&lt;System.Int32&gt;.</returns>
    public Task<int> AddBudgetAsync(IBudget e, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
        PostAsync<int>($"{_configurationOptions.ServiceEndpoint}/{ControllerNames.Budgets}", e, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following the answer given by @Chris Berlin, I tried the same but in my case, this problem was at the controller level- meaning while calling my API from the postman I was facing the issue (the action method parameter model class had interface properties).

I modified my startup.cs to use Newtonsoft.json instead of System.json by doing the following changes in my start.cs (along with @Chris Berlin's solution):

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();   //optional
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson();   //optional
```

and it worked.