How can I specify which class to deserialize an interface to in System.Text.Json in C#
Background
I am developing a chat application in C#. My solution consists of 3 libraries: One for the server, one for the client and a shared library that both the server and client use. The server and the client communicate over sockets (System.Net.Sockets) by sending each other messages in the following form:
/{some prefix} {data serialized into JSON}
(the data serialized into JSON is just an instance of a class that derives from PacketBase.
For example: public class LoginPacket : PacketBase simply contains a public string Username { get; }
Another example: public class LoginSucceededPacket : PacketBase contains public IUser User { get; })
For both the server and the client, a user should, let's say, consist of a username, and a list of group ids it is in, but both the server and the client should contain additional logic surrounding the user. (The client shouldn't [or doesn't need to] know how the logic on the server looks like and vice versa) So what I did is, I made an interface in the shared library IUser, and then a class BaseUser in both the server library and the client library which contain additional methods for the logic needed according to the library.
Now, the problem is, when a server wants to send an instance of a user to the client (for example when sending a LoginSucceededPacket). What I do is create that packet and serialize it. But since the LoginSucceededPacket contains a property of type IUser, the client cannot deserialize it (An exception is thrown when trying to deserialize it saying that you can't deserialize to an interface, which makes sense)
The question
So the question is, how can I specify what class the JsonSerializer should deserialize to when the property is of type IUser (or some other interface)? I have seen that you can use the [JsonDerivedType(typeof(*class*), "*className*")] tag on the interface, but that obviously does not work in my case, since I want to deserialize it to a different class depending on the assembly.
What I have tried
I have also seen that you can provide a type resolver to the JsonSerializer in the options, so I did just that:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
        {
            Modifiers = { TypeResolver.GetUserTypeResolver() }
        }
    };

and then making a TypeResolver class in both libraries:
public static class TypeResolver
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> GetUserTypeResolver()
    {
        return typeInfo =>
        {
            if (typeInfo.Type == typeof(IUser))
                typeInfo.CreateObject = () => new BaseUser();
        };
    }
}

Now, this does not throw an exception anymore, but the obvious downside is that I need to have an empty constructor in the BaseUser class. Because of that, I also need to make the setter for the Username property public, or else there would be no way for the json serializer to set it. However, despite making the setter public, the json does not set the username property on deserialization. I've gone into debugging mode to inspect the json and it did contain an entry for the username and despite that, the deserialized user did not have a username.
Why is that? Or is there another way to go about this problem?
Also, I am using NET 8.0...

It feels like you mixed up data and logic in the client class model? Maybe rather not do that and simply use classes for serialization and different classes for logic. And those problems coming from needing a certain inheritance chain will be gone.

Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147504/6868726

@Kiwimanshare nah I can't do that, because there are classes that contain an IUser property (e.g. the LoginSucceededPacket I mentioned above) which both the server and the client use, and the problem is that the server and the client have different implementations of IUser

@Ralf Do you mean that I should create a base class for the user in the shared library which the server and the client create a derived class from? I thought of that too, but that wouldn't work in another case. But can you confirm that is what you meant before I go ahead and explain that case to you?

I think Ralfs point is the use of "Data Transfer Object" (DTO). I.e. When the server needs to send something it converts the ServerUser into a UserDTO object that has no logic. The client deserializes the same UserDTO and converts it into a ClientUser.

Put all classes used to for communication into a separate project that is shared between server and client. Do not inherit from these classes, write code that converts the DTOs from/to the internal representation. It is a bit more code to write, but it can help with separating the client and server in a clean way.

@JonasH Ah ok, that makes sense. I just thought serializing and deserializing directly would be easier... Thank you

It is only initially easier until it gets somewhat more complex then the simplest of cases ;) It is good practice to separate concerns in different classes/models and then if needed map between. That separation is a bit of an extra first yes but makes maintaining/testing/extending way easier. It pays off medium-term. And additionally here it prevents having an inheritance chain. Inheritance should be used with caution. Implementing interfaces ok but actual inheritance rethink before using.

@Ralf alright thank you guys a lot. That solves my problem, but what now? I am new here so idk. Can you write that as an answer to the question rather than as a comment so I can mark it as correct, or should we leave it like this?

Leave it as it. We didn't solve your question but convinced you to do something else.

You could use AbstractToConcreteConverter<IUser, BaseUser> from this answer to System.Text.Json serialization doesn't work for abstract members to unconditionally deserialize IUser to BaseUser.  Does that answer your question fully?

@dbc That wouldn't work because I need to add an attribute to the interface, but what concrete class the interface property should be deserialized to depends on the assembly it is being deserialized in. As for the second way described in that answer (with the "ConcreteInterfaceSerializer"), I must say that I don't understand what that is about

What I mean is that when you are deserializing in an assembly where BaseUser implements IUser, you add new AbstractToConcreteConverter<IUser, BaseUser>() JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.  And when you are in an assembly where SomeOtherUser implements IUser you add new AbstractToConcreteConverter<IUser, SomeOtherUser>().  You are already customizing your options with a typeInfo modifier; the advantage of using the converter instead of the CreateObject method is that it works with parameterized constructors.

@dbc Oh yeah I know what you mean I just thought I had to add the attribute [JsonConverter(typeof(AbstractToConcreteConverter<IUser, BaseUser>))] which wouldn't work but it seems like you can also add the converter to the JsonSerializerOptions so I guess that solves it. Thank you!

You're welcome.  Should I mark this as a duplicate, or do you need an answer added?

Marking this as a duplicate is fine, I guess
