# Serialize list with base type into derived type json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API controller action which has a parameter of type CommandMessage. That type has a list with base types, CommandBase. My problem is that I can't make them to be of derived types, MyCommand in this example.

I'm using [JsonNetFormatter](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.Formatting.JsonNet/JsonNetFormatter.cs) from the Web API contrib project. It's using Json.Net as serializer.

Web API controller:

```
public class CommandController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(CommandMessage command)
    {
        //command.Commands[0].GetType().Name is always "CommandBase" instead of "MyCommand"
        var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                          {
                              Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Type of command 1 is '{0}'", command.Commands[0].GetType().FullName))
                          };
        return message;
    }
}
```

This i my request:

```
private void When()
    {
        using (client)
        {
            command = new MyCommand
                          {
                              CommandId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                              Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                              Name = "Martin"
                          };

            var message = new CommandMessage(Guid.NewGuid(),new List<CommandBase> {command});

            var requestMessage = GetHttpRequestMessage(message);
            var task = client.PostAsync("http://localhost.:16218/api/command", requestMessage.Content);
            task.Wait();
            responseMessage = task.Result;
        }
    }

private static HttpRequestMessage GetHttpRequestMessage<T>(T data)
    {
        var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var jsonFormatter = new JsonNetFormatter(DefaultJsonSettings.Settings());

        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage<T>(data, mediaType, new[] {jsonFormatter});

        return requestMessage;
    }
```

And as JSON:

```
{
  "$type": "PostToBaseClassList.Models.CommandMessage, PostToBaseClassList",
  "Commands": [
    {
      "$type": "PostToBaseClassList.Models.MyCommand, PostToBaseClassList",
      "Id": "45923a41-0c15-46e3-907d-64dd06840539",
      "Name": "Martin"
    }
  ],
  "MessageId": "c873970a-8621-4223-806e-b809039438ab"
}
```

The return message from the API controller action is:

> Type of command 1 is 'PostToBaseClassList.Models.CommandBase'

Command classes:

```
 [DataContract]
[XmlRoot]
public class MyCommand : CommandBase
{
    private readonly string name;

    public MyCommand()
    {
    }

    public MyCommand(Guid id, string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [XmlElement]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

 [DataContract]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public class CommandBase
{
    public Guid CommandId { get; set; }

    public static Type[] GetKnownTypes()
    {
        var query =
            from type in typeof (CommandBase).Assembly.GetTypes()
            where typeof (CommandBase).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            select type;

        var types = query.ToArray();
        return types;
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class CommandMessage
{
    public CommandMessage()
    {
    }

    public CommandMessage(Guid messageId, IEnumerable<CommandBase> commands)
    {
        MessageId = messageId;
        Commands = new List<CommandBase>(commands);
    }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public List<CommandBase> Commands { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public Guid MessageId { get; set; }
}
```

Json.Net settings:

```
//DefaultJsonSettings.Settings()
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                           {
                               NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                               TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                               Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
                                                {
                                                    new IsoDateTimeConverter
                                                        ()
                                                }
                           };

private static void RegisterFormatters(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var jsonNetFormatter = new JsonNetFormatter(DefaultJsonSettings.Settings());
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonNetFormatter);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just update the System.Net.Http.Formatting to 4.0.20710.0 and now I get many errors in the JsonNetFormatter class. Any clue?? Thanks

Comment: No, but you should create a new SO issue and describe your problem more in detail. What error do you get for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I added this row to RegisterFormatters()

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

This was not enough

```
config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonNetFormatter);
```

Full version

```
private void RegisterFormatters()
{
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
    var jsonNetFormatter = new JsonNetFormatter(DefaultJsonSettings.Settings());
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonNetFormatter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Json.NET does not respect `KnownTypes` attributes and you have to provide your own converters.

This question provides a few different solutions to this problem:
[Using Json.NET converters to deserialize properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties)

Comment: But shouldn't TypeNameHandling setting handle that?

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                           {
                               TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
                           };
        
Also found [this](http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/210326)

Comment: TypeNameHandling creates this in the json message `"$type": "PostToBaseClassList.Models.MyCommand, PostToBaseClassList"`