# Deserialising an implementation of an interface

Tags: c#, serialization, types, json.net, deserialization

Similar to [JSON.NET deserialize to object with Type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178323/json-net-deserialize-to-object-with-type-parameter), I need to deserialise some JSON, which has been previously serialised:

Serialisation code:

```
...
Data = new ImplementationofICommandData{ Id = Id }
DataType = typeof(ImplementationofICommandData).AssemblyQualifiedName,
...
```

Deserialisation code:

```
...
(ICommandData)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dto.Data, Type.GetType(dto.DataType))
...
```

In this case, dto.DataType contains the AssemblyFullName.

Initially, the projects that contained the serialisation and deserialisation shared a project with DTOs in it, so the deserialisation was able to use the same AssemblyQualifiedName for the type.

Now, I have a new project that is serialising data to the database. I have a DTO in the original shared project that has the exact same structure as the DTO in the new project, but due to being in a different assembly, the AssemblyQualified name that gets serialised does not correspond to a type about which the deserialising code knows.

Ideally, I won't have to make the serialisation and deserialisation code share the same DTO project, so is it possible to get the type by something less than the AssemblyQualifiedName? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, I've added a default namespace/assembly to search for a bare class name. This could be expanded to allow for a non-hack method of registration of a list of namespaces/assemblies in which to search for the DTO class, all wrapped up in some kind of resolver class.