# How does JSON.NET serialize objects when using EF table-per-hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework Code First [table-per-hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) in my ASP.NET Web API project.  One of my models has a List that is of the type of the abstract base class of the hierarchy.

```
List<Dog> // (for example; with GoldenRetriever, BorderCollie, etc inheriting)
```

I'm trying to test POSTing some data to my API Controller using Fiddler.  But I don't know how to represent the JSON when I do so.  If I try something like:

```
"Dogs":
[
    {"Name":"Bud", "Age":"3"}
]
```

I get the error:

> "Could not create an instance of type Models.Dog. Type is an interface
>   or abstract class and cannot be instantiated."

Specifying the Discriminator in the JSON doesn't help me either.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

**Edit: Solution**

The trick is to use the $type property in the JSON string.  For more information see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net) suggested by m.t.bennett in the comments.

To enable using the $type property I needed to add the following to WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling 
    = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

Then when posting the JSON to Fiddler, I added the $type property with the full object path:

```
{"$type":"Example.Models.Dogs.GoldenRetriever, Example.Models",
    "Name":"Bud","Age":3}
```

For me to figure out this formatting I used Snixtor's suggestion to serialize an object and output the JSON string.  Brilliant!

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution since it's [JSON.NET specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390801/1621156), but it works!

Comment: I find the best way to determine JSON formatting for a model is to serialize an existing instance *to* JSON. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Snixtor Great advice (and will use this in the future), but it didn't help.  I used JsonConvert to serialize the list and it spat out basically what I was trying already.  There was no evidence of any way to discriminate between object types.

Comment: does this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348215/how-to-deserialize-json-into-ienumerablebasetype-with-newtonsoft-json-net help at all?

Comment: @m.t.bennett That did help!  Using your suggestion and Snixtor's we solved the riddle.  I'll update my answer with the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom JsonConverter to handle the base-type deserialization.

```
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return typeof(Mybase).Equals(objectType);
    }

    public override MyBase Deserialize(JsonReader reader, MyBase existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var ret = existingValue;
        var jobj = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);
        if (jobj["type"] == null || jobj["type"].Type != JTokenType.String)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Supplied JSON is missing the required 'type' member.");

        var typeName = jobj["type"].Value<string>();

        var t = this.GetType().Assembly.GetType("MyNamespace." + typeName);
        if(t == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(String.Format("Could not identify supplied type '{0}' as a known type.", typeName));

        if (existingValue != null && !t.IsInstanceOfType(existingValue))
            throw new JsonSerializationException(String.Format("Type Mismatch: existingValue {0} is not assignable from supplied Type {1}", existingValue.GetType().Name, t.Name));

        ret = (ContactMethod)jobj.ToObject(t);

        return ret;
    }
```

And registered the JsonConverter durring application initialization:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings;
settings.Converters.Add(new MyBaseConverter());
```