# Lists, Interfaces and Objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface

I've a requirement for a custom list.

I've defined its interface like this...

```
public interface IMyList: IList<IMyListItem>
{
    // Stuff
}
```

and the concrete class is defined like this ...

```
public class MyList : List<IMyListItem>, IMyList
{

}
```

All is good.

Until, I try and deserialize something into an instance of `MyList`. When I do that using something like this ...

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyList>(someString)
```

JSon.NET complains with this message...

> Message=Could not create an instance of type IMyListItem. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

I get what the message is telling me, but I can't work out what do do with my class and interface definitions.

I could change the definition of `MyList` to `public class MyList : List<MyListItem>` but then the interface is dependent on a concrete class and, more importantly for me, it creates a circular reference (my Models and the interfaces that define them are in separate assemblies).

Am I just doing it wrong? It it not reasonable to have the Interfaces and Class implementations in different assemblies? Is there a technique/pattern that I should be using for this that I'm not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.NET - Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644464/json-net-type-is-an-interface-or-abstract-class-and-cannot-be-instantiated)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net

Comment: What does your `MyList` give you that a simple `List<MyListItem>` wouldn't?  You might want to consider composition instead of inheritance here.

Comment: _sigh_. Moments after posting the Q it came to me. Simply call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IMyListItem>>(someString)` instead.

Comment: @juharr. I have a number of custom set operations in the MyList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a generic type with an inheritance restriction?

```
public interface IMyList<T>: IList<T> where T : IMyListItem
{
    // Stuff
}

public class MyList : List<MyListItem>, IMyList<MyListItem>
{

}
```

...and using it like so:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyList>(someString)
```

Your interface will then not be based on a concrete class, but on an inheritance restriction to another interface instead. Your MyList class on the other hand wont have to be a list of interfaces (IMyListItem) but instead a list of MyListItems instead.

Answer (score 0):

A few people have pointed me to other answers, all of which I will check out but, in this specific instance I realised I could just change the call to deserialize the object from ...

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyList>(someString)
```

to

```
var result = new MyList();
result.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyListEntry>>(someString));
```