# Serialize and deserialize a hierarchy of a C# class to Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Is there a way to serialize and then deserialize a class that has a member variable of unknown type that could be either be a simple value type or an instance of the containing class itself ?

```
public class A
{
    public dynamic Value { get; set; }//Value could be int or type A for example
}

public static class ASerializer
{
    public static string ToJson(A table)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);//using Json.Net
    }

    public static A FromJson(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
    }
}

public class Tests
{
    public static void TestASerialization()
    {
        var a = new A() { Value = 1 };
        var aa = new A { Value = a };
        var aaa = new A { Value = aa };
        var json = ASerializer.ToJson(aaa);
        var aaa2 = ASerializer.FromJson(json);

        var aa2 = (A)aaa2.Value;    //throws
    }
}
```

if I serialize and then deserialize aaa - I can't cast the Value of the deserialized aaa back to type A I get:

Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 
'A'

Any suggestions on handling this nested hierarchy elegantly, without resorting to hand coding ?
Seems to work with just one instance of A with Value of type A.

Comment: You can use [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) to serialize polymorphic properties and retain the type after deserialization.

Comment: To apply `TypeNameHandling` to a specific property see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties/6303853#6303853).

Comment: thanks, I did try this but obviously didn't implement it correctly using JsonSerializerSettings with property of TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All worked

Answer (score 0):

You aren't casting what you think you're casting.

In this case, you're actually casting the `Value` property to `A`.  You need to wrap the `aaa2` instance in params with the cast before accessing the property.

```
var aa2 = ((A)aaa2).Value;
```

Comment: typo and not really relevant, the exception message kind of made that clear

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic is a compiler hack mostly, I would recommend generics instead. 
@David L 's answer is also correct.

```
public class A<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how exactly can you restrict a generic to just a value type of int and the type A given ?

Comment: A<int> something = new A<int>();
something.Value = 1; //no problem
something.Value = "";//exception

Comment: poor phrasing on my part, my actual requirement is for class A to hold a value that could be a value type or itself - and I want to prevent any other type to be used. In the actual implementation which I have not added above as it wasn't relevant to the serialization problem, I would restrict the possible range of types supported by use of overloaded constructors and accessor methods. Your example above would allow someone to create an instance of A that holds any type at all.