# Convert properties when Deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

From an HTTP GET Request I have the following result as string:

```
{
  "id": "5963363",
  "private": "0",
  "created_at": "2021-06-02 16:15:40",
  "release_date": "2021-06-02 16:15:40",
  "release_timestamp": 1622643340,
  "user_id": "10037997",
  "duration": "16",
  "permalink": "the-shortest-interview-of-magnus-carlsen-only-10-seconds",
  "description": "",
  "geo": "",
  "tags": "",
  "taged_artists": "",
  "bpm": "92.5",
  "key": "Bm",
  "license": "",
  "version": "",
  "type": "",
  "downloadable": "1",
  "genre": "Other",
  "genre_slush": "other",
  "title": "The Shortest Interview of Magnus Carlsen - ONLY 10 SECONDS!",
  "uri": "https://api-v2.hearthis.at/sergiu-molnar/the-shortest-interview-of-magnus-carlsen-only-10-seconds/",
  "permalink_url": "https://hearthis.at/sergiu-molnar/the-shortest-interview-of-magnus-carlsen-only-10-seconds/",
  "thumb": "https://images.hearthis.at/1/_/2/_/uploads/dummy/w200_h200_q70_----1_2021_04-2.jpg",
  "artwork_url": "https://images.hearthis.at/1/_/2/_/uploads/dummy/w500_q70_----1_2021_04-2.jpg",
  "artwork_url_retina": "https://images.hearthis.at/1/_/2/_/uploads/dummy/w1000_q70_----1_2021_04-2.jpg",
  "background_url": "https://images.hearthis.at/1/_/2/_/uploads/dummy/w565_h565_c000000_q70_----1_2021_04-2.jpg",
  "waveform_data": "https://cdn.hearthis.at/_/wave_data/10037997/3000_6ab732ed56cc403f09c0dc9f86f80342.mp3_1622643340.js",
  "waveform_url": "https://cdn.hearthis.at/_/cache/waveform_mask/5/9/5963363.png",
  "user": {
    "id": "10037997",
    "permalink": "sergiu-molnar",
    "username": "Sergiu Molnar",
    "caption": "",
    "uri": "https://api-v2.hearthis.at/sergiu-molnar/",
    "permalink_url": "https://hearthis.at/sergiu-molnar/",
    "avatar_url": "https://images.hearthis.at/1/_/2/_/uploads/dummy/w512_q70_----1_2021_08-2.jpg"
  },
  "stream_url": "https://hearthis.app/sergiu-molnar/the-shortest-interview-of-magnus-carlsen-only-10-seconds/listen/?s=vCc",
  "preview_url": "https://preview.hearthis.at/files/6ab732ed56cc403f09c0dc9f86f80342.mp3",
  "download_url": "https://hearthis.app/sergiu-molnar/the-shortest-interview-of-magnus-carlsen-only-10-seconds/download/",
  "download_filename": "The Shortest Interview of Magnus Carlsen - ONLY 10 SECONDS! (hearthis.at).mp3",
  "playback_count": "1",
  "download_count": "0",
  "favoritings_count": "0",
  "reshares_count": "0",
  "comment_count": "0",
  "played": false,
  "favorited": false,
  "liked": false,
  "reshared": false
}
```

As you can see, almost all properties are strings even these should be `int` or `date`.

What I'm trying to do is to Deserialize the object and Convert the properties.
For this, I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` as follow:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrackDetails>(response);
```

This is the `TrackDetails` class:

```
public class TrackDetails
{
     [JsonProperty("id")]
     public string Id { get; set; }

     ...
}
```

Because in the result, the `Id` is a string and I want this as int, after I read those articles:

- [How to convert a property type when deserializing json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47411464/how-to-convert-a-property-type-when-deserializing-json)
- [Using Json.NET converters to deserialize properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties/4093750#4093750)

I have tried to create a custom converter like this one:

```
public class StringToIntConverter : JsonConverter
{
     public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
     {
          return (objectType == typeof(string));
     }

     public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
     {
          return int.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
     }

     public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
     {
          writer.WriteValue(int.Parse((string)value));
     }
}
```

And this was applied like this:

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringToIntConverter))]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
  Message=Error setting value to 'Id' on 'API.Models.TrackDetails'.

Inner Exception 1:
  InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: Shouldn't `public string Id { get; set; }` be `public int Id { get; set; }` ? As for dates, [the standard way](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-json-i-json#section-4.3) is to serialize them as ISO8601 strings. Have you tried using `DatetTime` as the type for `release_timestamp` ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to declare them as `int` or `DateTime` (the type I expected) assuming they will be automatically converted, but like this, I'm getting the following error for `int` for e.g: `Could not convert string to boolean: 0`

Comment: That's a different thing completely. `0` is a number, not a bool  (true,false). There's no if or but about dates. That's how they work. [ints are also converted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783225/json-deserialization-string-is-automatically-converted-to-int).

Comment: With converter, should you not specify the the required type `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringToIntConverter))]
 public int Id {get ;set;}`? In your case, it should be `int Id` instead of `string Id`

Comment: As for booleans, what you posted uses `"played": false,`, not a string and definitely not a number. There's `"downloadable": "1"` but I suspect that's really a number, as the rest of the document uses boolean values

Comment: Post the *actual* class you tried to use, not just a single property. I suspect most if not problems are caused by typos and mismatches.

Comment: Oh, I understood the problem. So I have to create a converter only from `string` to `bool`. I understood. Thank you, guys.

Comment: @SergiuMolnar only if you want to handle eg `private` as a boolean, even though the document clearly uses boolean values for `played`, `favorited` etc. Are you *sure* that `private` is a boolean? Shouldn't you contact the author then? Clearly, they're using different ways to output the same type. Unless those properties *aren't* booleans but numbers?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. In the response, as you mentioned @PanagiotisKanavos `"downloadable": "1"` could not be converted from string to bool without an explicit converter.