# c# how to deserialize IFormFile

Tags: c#, api, serialization, iformfile

I'm sure somebody had the same problem, but I didn't find anything. 
I send post request to get the file, and I get this model as a response:

```
    public class ResponseWithFile
{
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public List<int> Errors { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

I get this response from a controller:

```
    [Route("get")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile([FromBody]GetFileDto request)
    {
        var result = _fileService.GetFile(request.Id, request.ContentType);
        if (result.IsSuccessful)
            return Ok(result);
        return BadRequest(result);
    }
```

The response is correct, I can read it into a string, but when I try to deserialize it into response object I get error:

```
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        string respString = string.Empty;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            respString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var serResp = (ResponseWithFile)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respString);//error here
```

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'ServiceModels.ResponseWithFile

I'm sure it's because of IFormFile object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :(

Comment: Isn't `IFormFile` used to represent a file that *uploaded* to a web service, i.e. when using a `<form>`? `ResponseWithFile` suggests you try to use it as the response when *downloading* a file.

Comment: Show us your `respString` JSON string so that we can see what data you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var serResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseWithFile>(respString);
```

or

```
  var serResp = (ResponseWithFile)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respString, typeof(ResponseWithFile));
```

Comment: now I get JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.
looks like I shouldn't use IFormFile to receive files

Comment: @Jamil, Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties. I believe, you will get answer

Comment: @Jamil looks like you should start reading your exceptions messages. _"Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated"_ means that `IFormFile` is an **interface** and cannot be instantiated. No one can instantiate an instance of interface.

Comment: The problem was that I was not reading from stream correctly, and I probably shouldn't use IFormFile there. I will accept this answer, because technically it is a solution to my problem(though problem was in a different place).