# Dynamically create a type for JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync?

Tags: c#, types

I have method/Task where I would like to return a type which implementing some interface.
I am choosing the type with lot of conditions and I have strong feeling, that it could be done simpler. Problem is, that I don't know how to choose type dynamically.

This is OK:

```
IInterface Obj;
//Type1 and Type2 implements IInterface
if(true)
{
    Obj = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Type1>(memoryStream, JsonOpt);
    return Obj;
}
else
{
    Obj = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Type2>(memoryStream, JsonOpt);
    return Obj;
}
```

This not:

```
IInterface Obj;
Type type;
//Type1 and Type2 implements IInterface
if(true)
{
    type = typeof(Type1);
}
else
{
    type = typeof(Type2);
}
Obj = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<type>(memoryStream, JsonOpt);
return Obj
```

I know I can use generics, but in the end of the day, the problem will be same. Here is some generic task.

```
    public class Test
    {
        public async Task<T> Ooo<T>() where T : new()
        {
            T t = new T();
            //something awaitable here
            return t;
        }
    }
```

here I have to decide the type:

```
        Test test = new();
        Type t;
        if (true)
        {
            t = typeof(TimeZoneInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            t = typeof(TimeZone);
        }
        object obj = await test.Ooo<typeof(t)>();
```

Comment: Does the sample code in my answer here potentially help? I'm not sure where your memory stream is coming from or if you're the source of it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69480735/4800344

Comment: I have to check it deeply, but yes, that could help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync), there's a non-generic overload which accepts the type you want to deserialize to. You just need to cast the returned `object` to the appropriate interface.

```
Type type = ...;
object result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(memoryStream, type, JsonOpt);
return (IInterface)result;
```

Comment: The issue is that they don't know the type straight away

Comment: Are you sure? As I read the question, the issue is that they have a `Type` instance chosen based on some conditions, but can't call the generic method since the type isn't known at compile-time.

Comment: I thought they're trying to check which concrete type it is, deserialise to concrete type and then return the concrete class as `IInterface` - so that they can then cast it outside of the method?

Comment: Which, if they can get the correct `Type`, is exactly what my answer does. :)

Comment: The `if(true)` is throwing me off on what they actually want - you're probably right, ignore me 

Comment: I wrote if(true) for example, i didnt want to copy some confusing expresion from my code